# Tapkey Management API IdentityProvider Users: Deleting / (Updating)?

Tags: tapkey

Regarding: https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_v1/#/

Is there a way to delete / (update) IdentityProvider Users? The doc only talks about read and create.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation, there is no delete/update endpoint for Identity Provider Users as of today.